# Clojure macro throws "CompilerException java.lang.IllegalStateException: Var clojure.core/unquote is unbound" when called

Tags: macros, functional-programming, clojure, lisp

I'm trying to write a clojure macro that lets me call a function and retrieve the arguments from a map/struct using the provided key values such as:

```
   (with-params  {:apple 2 :banana 3 :cherry 7} + :apple :banana)
   ;; 5
```

but when I try to use the macro that I wrote:

```
(defmacro with-params [s f & symbols]
  `(~f ~@(map ~s ~symbols)))
```

calling

```
   (with-params  {:apple 2 :banana 3 :cherry 7} + :apple :banana)
```

gives me

```
#<CompilerException java.lang.IllegalStateException: Var clojure.core/unquote is unbound. (NO_SOURCE_FILE:0)>
```

Could someone help me understand how syntax-quoting works here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason that `` `(~f ~@(map ~s ~symbols)) `` doesn't work is that the compiler chokes on the unnecessary `unquote` (`~`) inside the `unquote-splicing` (`~@`). The `unquote-splicing` unquotes the outer `syntax-quote` (`` ` ``), so the inner two `unquote`s don't have any matching `syntax-quote`, which is why you were getting the "unbound" error.

What you want to do is evaluate `(map s symbols)` first to get the sequence of operands, then pass the flattened result to the function (`~f`); therefore the correct version is:

```
(defmacro with-params [s f & symbols] `(~f ~@(map s symbols)))
```

You can easily verify this with:

```
(macroexpand '(with-params {:a 1 :b 2 :c 5} * :a :b :c))    ;; (* 1 2 5)
(with-params {:a 1 :b 2 :c 5} * :a :b :c)                   ;; 10
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice!, but could you clarify on why putting the `~@` before `map` causes the compiler problems? I thought that I would be able to make a list expression by splicing the results of map into it but I think `apply` in this case does work better.

Comment: @Scott: After giving it a bit of thought, I came up with the solution I should have originally. Hope it's a little more clear now. If my answer is helpful, you can upvote it or mark it as accepted.

Comment: strictly it should be (defmacro with-params [s f & symbols] `(~f ~@(map (fn [symbol] (list symbol s)) symbols)) as this will allow for the map/struct to be evaluated at runtime.

Comment: OK, I see what you mean now. I'd vote for your answer but I don't have enough reputation :/

Comment: @cool Danger, danger, you're now causing the caller's code to evaluate `s` once per symbol argument. If construction of `s` is expensive or side-effectful, this will be confusing and unpleasant. For example, something like `(with-params (do (println "computing...") {:x 1 :y 2}) (fn [a b] (+ a b)) :y :x)` will print `"computing..."` twice.

Answer (score 4):

For what it's worth, this shouldn't be a macro anyway. A function is plenty powerful, and the macro version will only work if both the map and the keywords are given as compile-time literals.

```
(defmacro with-params-macro [s f & symbols]
  `(~f ~@(map s symbols)))

(defn with-params-fn [s f & symbols]
  (apply f (map s symbols)))

user> (with-params-macro {:x 1} (fn [z] z) :x)
1
user> (let [params {:x 1}] 
        (with-params-macro params (fn [z] z) :x))
nil

user> (let [params {:x 1}] 
        (with-params-fn params (fn [z] z) :x))
1
```

Comment: +1 Very good point. The original question *is* about macros, but as we often see on SO, it's good to un-ask the question sometimes.